# How to open cygwin & execute bash in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cygwin, mintty

I am trying to build my custom-commands in Eclipse.
This is Eclipse plugin which I am using: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/startexplorer

It looks like this (link to image):

[Custom commands in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4neMz.jpg)

I need eclipse variables in custom commands:

```
${resource_loc} , ${selected_resource_loc} , ${workspace_loc} , etc...
```

It should be something like this:

```
D:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/bash -l -c "cd ${workspace_loc}"
```

But mintty will close this window immediately. I need to execute command based on eclipse variable **and** go to bash interactive mode, without closing window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a StartExplorer custom command, that opens a Cygwin terminal and
starts an interactive Bash shell in the filesystem location of the selected
resource, follow these steps:

1. Make sure to install [chere](https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/chere/)
    Cygwin package;
2. Install [StartExplorer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/startexplorer)
    Eclipse plugin;
3. In Eclipse Preferences for plugin StartExplorer, create a new custom
    command:

   - Command: `D:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -e /bin/xhere /bin/bash
     "${selected_resource_loc}"`
   - Enabled for Resources: `yes`
   - Name for Resources Menu: `Cygwin Bash Here`
   - Resource Type: `Folders`

Alternatively to steps 2 and 3, if you don't care about context-menu entry, no
need to install the StartExplorer plugin.
Eclipse `Extenal Tools Configuration` standard feature will do the trick.

In `Run > Extenal Tools Configuration`, create a new Program:

- Name: `Cygwin Bash Here`
- Location: `D:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe`
- Arguments: `-e /bin/xhere /bin/bash "${selected_resource_loc}"`

Basically, the `xhere` script (part of `chere` package) performs the following steps:

1. indicate to the login shells not to `cd $HOME` (`export CHERE_INVOKING=true`, which is checked for in `/etc/profile`);
2. change to the directory passed as 2nd argument (`cd "$2"`);
3. Execute the shell passed as 1st argument as a login shell (`exec -l $1`).

*Note:* if you replace `/bin/bash` with `/etc/passwd`, the current user's login shell read from `/etc/passwd` is used instead of `bash`.

Comment: Awesome thanks a ton for this! If only I could get the Cygwin window to be one of the tabs inside Eclipse like how the Console View is...